# Plot and Legends in Matlab/ Using different colors for same signal

Tags: matlab, plot

So I have this code

```
if (e(i)>mean(e))
      fprintf('V1\n\n'); %E=High; Voiced
      c='r';
  end;

  if ((ntz(i)<mean(ntz))& (e(i)<mean(e)) & (e(i)>0.00005))
      fprintf('V2\n\n')';  % E= Low, NTZ= Low; Voiced
      c='r';
  end;

  if ((ntz(i)>mean(ntz))& (e(i)<mean(e)) & (e(i)>0.00005)) 
      fprintf('UN\n\n'); % NTZ=High; E=Low; Unvoiced
     c='b';
  end;

  if (e(i)< 0.00005)   %E=approx 0; Silence
      fprintf('S\n\n')';
      c='g';
  end;

  aux=y((i-1)*N+1:i*N);
  ttx=tx(i):1/fs:tx(i)+(N-1)/fs;
  plot(ttx,aux,c); 
  xlabel('Time');
  ylabel('Signal Amplitude');
  title('Voiced Unvoiced Silence Detection');
```

You can see that on the same plot/signal I have three colors.

My problem is that I want to create a legend which must say: Red = Voiced, Blue = Unvoiced, Green= Silence

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: Assign multiple colors to text in legend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194096/matlab-assign-multiple-colors-to-text-in-legend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are doing this inside a loop (for each `i`). To assign legend labels, you could store the returned handle of each line object, and use that at the end to give labels to each:

```
for i=1:3
    %# ...
    h(i) = plot(x,y,clr);
end
legend(h, {'Plot1','Plot2','Plot3'})
```